# Dockerized Spring boot app connect to database docker image

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a basic spring boot application with gradle which makes calls to an Oracle database and the database properties are specified in an application.properties file.

I created a Docker image of the spring boot application with the plugin "com.google.cloud.tools.jib" and using the following command:

```
./gradlew jibDockerBuild --image=app1
```

I have a docker-compose file in which i specify the image as an service and i want the application to start when i run the command: "docker-compose up"

The docker-compose file is the following:

```
version: '3'
    services:
        app1:
            image: "app1"
            ports:
                - "8731:8731"
```

But when I hit the run the "docker-compose up" command in CMD I recieve the following exception:

```
 java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

More informations:

1. My Oracle database is a docker container with the name : "ORA12201_1" and port 3769
2. Inside the application.properties the database properties specified are correct since I am amble to start the application from IntelliJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can connect from IntelliJ without problem as the container exposes the port (3769) to the host (your PC), but now you are trying to connect from one Docker container to another.
The containers do not share the network (isolation) so you need to connect them.

One of the recommended approach is **User-defined networks**

Create first a network

```
docker network create --driver bridge my_network
```

Run the applications

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 --network my_network -d --name=postgres postgres
docker run -p 5050:80 --network my_network -d --name=pgadmin dpage/pgadmin4
```

You can verify they are effectively running on the same network with

```
docker network inspect my_network
```

**Spring Boot config**

You can now connect from one to another using `host.docker.internal` as hostname, for example in your Spring Boot application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/postgres
```

Comment: Is there any other recommended approach beside the creation of a user-defined network ? I thought that was possible to specify the database container as a volume or service

Comment: Hello, Docker volumes are basically storage (folders) which indeed you can share, but your app needs to 'talk' to Oracle. 
In Kubernetes is different, you can have a service attached to your app, but thats a different technology

Comment: But can we also deploy this custom network ? Or how the process of deploying this apps in a Linux machine with this Dockerfile would work ?

Comment: It works the same wherever you have Docker, if you mean a production-like environment you might want to look at using docker-compose (easier config) or an extra layer like Docker Swarm or Kubernetes