# Spring Boot Plugins With A Database Docker Image

Tags: spring-boot

I use the new Spring Boot Plugins on 2.3 to build a Docker image of a simple Spring Boot application as stated in [the Docker guide](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/) on spring.io.

```
$ ./mvnw spring-boot:build-image
```

And using jib to get the application run on Kubernetes. The application doesn't use a database at this moment.

Now, I need to use a database in the application. The command yields that I need either add to a memory-based database or a profile set up with database configuration. I don't want to use a memory-based database like H2, but a PostgreSQL.

What shall I do with the plug-in to get a Docker image of the database so that a database only can be used by the application, but not others?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to run a Postgresql db you can just run the Docker command to get and run it

`docker run -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres`

This will download the latest available version from DockerHub and run it on your local dev environment.

You can then connect from SpringBoot using the exposed port (5432)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=mysecretpassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

`

Comment: Thanks for your info. That shall work. I didn't state clearly my indication in my post. What I need is to have a DB for the application only. I will have more than one applications and they will use the same type of DB separately. So, I am wondering whether I can put a DB inside the application Docker image or not.

Comment: I need to use Docker compose for the situation.

Comment: You dont have to but I agree it simplifies since you control all your containers (and network) in one file. The approach I suggested instead runs 2 docker runs to achieve the same.

Comment: I actually can't get it working for my app docker image with the DB docker image. I run "docker run -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -d postgres" and run "psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -W" to access the DB console. With a DB configuration in my application similar with yours (I use reactive DBC so it is little different spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres). And I get "refused connect to localhost:5432" although userid and password are set correctly. I might make a mistake on something.

Comment: Ok, if you want to connect from a Docker container to another container then you need to setup a network between those, I have answered something similar already, have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60003840/dockerized-spring-boot-app-connect-to-database-docker-image/60004798#60004798

Comment: Thanks for the info. That is one way to connect DB from an app. I haven't seen the approach before.